# Hibernate Spring JPA annotations exception on context initialization - NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Having this problem. Seems to deploy okay then the problem reappears... Can't figure out what's up. Tried from both netbeans and intellij, tried on tomcat and jetty.

Looks like it's somehow related to JPA annotations... Unsure how to proceed. Could this be related to my jdk?

Pom.xml for the services module that uses annotations.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
        hpweb
        hpweb
        1.0
    
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>service</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate.version>3.5.4-Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<repositories>

</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <groupId>hpweb</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- SQLite JDBC library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->


    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate library dependecy start >
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency-->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Generic dao -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sakaiproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>generic-dao</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.soundcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-api-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

stack trace

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.heavypressure.service.IUserService com.heavypressure.web.controller.impl.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.heavypressure.orm.dao.impl.UserDao com.heavypressure.service.impl.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/tripled153/IdeaProjects/heavypressure/hpweb/web/target/web/WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0.jar!/com/heavypressure/orm/dao/impl/UserDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.heavypressure.service.IUserService com.heavypressure.web.controller.impl.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.heavypressure.orm.dao.impl.UserDao com.heavypressure.service.impl.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/tripled153/IdeaProjects/heavypressure/hpweb/web/target/web/WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0.jar!/com/heavypressure/orm/dao/impl/UserDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.heavypressure.orm.dao.impl.UserDao com.heavypressure.service.impl.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/tripled153/IdeaProjects/heavypressure/hpweb/web/target/web/WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0.jar!/com/heavypressure/orm/dao/impl/UserDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.heavypressure.orm.dao.impl.UserDao com.heavypressure.service.impl.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/tripled153/IdeaProjects/heavypressure/hpweb/web/target/web/WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0.jar!/com/heavypressure/orm/dao/impl/UserDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/tripled153/IdeaProjects/heavypressure/hpweb/web/target/web/WEB-INF/lib/service-1.0.jar!/com/heavypressure/orm/dao/impl/UserDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [service-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints()[Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a couple of the dependencies also relied on hibernate and so were downloading their own copies at specified versions. I actually  ditched them but I think you can do a maven ignore in the config. I don't want to use any libraries that couple me to a specific version of hibernate anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this line:

```
    ... 
    nested exception is 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.uniqueConstraints [Ljavax/persistence/UniqueConstraint; 
    ...
```

Therefore, something must be wrong with dependencies for `javax.persistence.Table`.

This must help you put proper dependencies:

http://mavenhub.com/c/javax/persistence/Table/dependency

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this actually wasn't helpful. I've tried adding jpa dependencies of all shapes and sizes. I think it's related to maven jdk source instructions.

Comment: Hey! I can't believe it - I tried a day putting every shape and size of jpa dependency in the project. Finally this one worked (I think!) I'm going to try a bit more but leaving this here. <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.spec.ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>ow2-javaee-5-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: It's odd I still get a "@Table not applicable to this type" error in netbeans so something must be screwed up with the jpa annotation dependencies so I still can't use the @Table annotation. I can deploy randomly sometimes.

Comment: I would suggest downloading all the jar files manually and adding them to the class path and see if it works in this way. I mean doing the maven job by yourself. It looks a bit strange doing it in this way; but eventually you will be able to sort out the issue, I guess. I have a consistent configuration at my disposal right now, which is consistence and works for me. It is Spring V3.2.0 and Hibernate 4.1.5. You could try this and see if it works for you as well.